# Javascript: can't change background on div click or change marginLeft on element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to test changing `backgroundColor` and `marginLeft` on this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/ntqLo6v0/2/

and couldn't make it work.

```js
var collapsed = 0;

$('[data-toggle=collapse-button]').click(function() {
  if (collapsed == 0) {
    close();
  } else {
    open();
  }

});

function close() {
  document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

  (document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]).style.marginLeft = "20px";

  collapsed = 1;
}

function open() {
  document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundColor = "red";

  (document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]).style.marginLeft = "120px";

  collapsed = 0;
}
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="button" data-toggle="collapse-button">
  button
</div>

<div class="content">
  some content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just a little issue: `$('[data-toggle=collapse-button]')`.

You are using jQuery but do not define it. That's why you get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the console.

Here is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntqLo6v0/7/) where I added jQuery (in the resources left) in order to make your example running.